# How to pass this (jQuery selector) to setTimeout() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This works as expected:

```js
$('.lock').click(function() {
  $('.fa-lock', this).addClass('fa-flip');
  $('.fa-unlock', this).addClass('fa-flip');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.fa-lock').css('color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)');
    $('.fa-unlock').css('color', 'green');
  }, 600);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
  @keyframes halfflip {
    to {
      transform: rotateY(360deg);
    }
  }
  
  .fa-flip {
    animation-name: halfflip;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }
  
</style>
<div class="fa-5x fa-stack lock">
  <i class="fas fa-unlock fa-stack-1x" style="--fa-animation-duration: 4s; --fa-animation-iteration-count: 1; color: transparent; animation-fill-mode: forwards; --fa-animation-delay:-2s"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-lock fa-stack-1x" style="--fa-animation-duration: 4s; --fa-animation-iteration-count: 1; color: red; animation-fill-mode: forwards; --fa-animation-delay:-2s"></i>
</div>
```

But this doesn't:

```js
$('.lock').click(function() {
  $('.fa-lock', this).addClass('fa-flip');
  $('.fa-unlock', this).addClass('fa-flip');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.fa-lock', this).css('color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)');
    $('.fa-unlock', this).css('color', 'green');
  }, 600);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
  @keyframes halfflip {
    to {
      transform: rotateY(360deg);
    }
  }
  
  .fa-flip {
    animation-name: halfflip;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }
  
</style>
<div class="fa-5x fa-stack lock">
  <i class="fas fa-unlock fa-stack-1x" style="--fa-animation-duration: 4s; --fa-animation-iteration-count: 1; color: transparent; animation-fill-mode: forwards; --fa-animation-delay:-2s"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-lock fa-stack-1x" style="--fa-animation-duration: 4s; --fa-animation-iteration-count: 1; color: red; animation-fill-mode: forwards; --fa-animation-delay:-2s"></i>
</div>
```

How to correctly pass `this` to `setTimeout()` function without declaring a variable holding the jQuery selector?

Adding "some more details". Adding "some more details". Adding "some more details". Adding "some more details". Adding "some more details".

Comment: Use an arrow function inside the timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this

```
$('.lock').click(function() {
$('.fa-lock', this).addClass('fa-flip');
$('.fa-unlock', this).addClass('fa-flip');
setTimeout(()=>{
    $('.fa-lock', this).css('color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)');
    $('.fa-unlock', this).css('color', 'green');
  }, 600);
});
```

The reason this works and not the other one is, arrow function uses `this` of parent scope in its scope while a function defined with `function` keyword initializes its own `this` instance within its scope